# Is it called a residential area or residential location or some proper name?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

Here is a brief discription about my residence:

> There are around fifty apartment buildings in ABC Garden. Each building has thirty stories, and there are 10 flats in each story.

My friend asked me where I live.
Instead of telling him the full address, I just said, "I am living in ABC Garden, city name".

Given that "ABC Garden, city name" is not a full address, should it be called a residential area or residential location in this case?

Comment: The important word here is "living".  You *live* in an area, whereas something exists or happens at a location. This is a nice location for a high-rise apartment building, overlooking the park, and the area has many shops and small restaurants.

Comment: I concur with @TRomano. Though, Jameswebster has provided a very good answer, but I still think that you should opt for "residential area."

Comment: In most contexts, everyone except speakers of "Indian English" would say *I **live** in [some area]*. The progressive form *I **am living** [somewhere]* is normally only used in contexts where you specifically wish to imply ***...now, at the present time*** (i.e. - you want your audience to take note that you *didn't* live there in the past and/or won't in the future).

Comment: From the description, I would call "ABC Garden" a *neighborhood*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say neither of your options quite hits the mark.

I would suggest that what you gave him was a **partial address**. I might also use the terms **region**, **locale** or **district**

- **[Region](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/region)** -  an area, especially part of a country or the world having definable characteristics but not always fixed boundaries
- **[Locale](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/locale)** - a place where something happens or is set
- **[District](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/district)** - an area of a country or city, especially one characterized by a particular feature or activity

---

I don't think **residential area** is wrong per se. Just not quite right. Specifically, I would say a residential area is any connected set of smaller areas. e.g. London is a large commercial district surrounded by a very large residential area.

However, this may be regional since "In India, it is perfectly okay to use "residential area" whenever referring to the are we live in." – [Usernew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/20213/usernew)

Comment: I don't think her options are wrong. I think "residential area" is perfect in the OP's context.

Comment: I didn't think they were **wrong** per se. Just not quite right. Specifically, I would say a residential area would contain more than just the one place they are referring to. e.g. `London is a large commercial district surrounded by a very large residential area`

Comment: I think it depends on how the reader interprets its meaning. In India, it is perfectly okay to use "residential area" whenever referring to the are we live in.

Comment: Thank Usernew, and James Webster for the quick help. Hi, James Webster. Since "ABC Garden, city name" is a partial address, is it correct if I call it my living locale?

Comment: For example: Whenever we want to say what area we live in, we say "Paschim  Vihar." Now this is what [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschim_Vihar) has to say. And I think this is what the OP really meant by saying "ABC Garden."

Comment: @Kitty, not quite. The syntax is a little wrong. "Locale" is probably the least commonly used word in this list, so it's a little harder to use correctly. `I live in the ABC district` is probably your easiest option.

Comment: @Usernew Ahah! Thank you Usernew, it seems the Apple dictionary uses Oxford Dictionaries.

Comment: *area @JamesWebster No problemo :)